# Is there a function in R to give the lack of fit and pure error of an ANOVA completed on a half 2^k factorial with centre points?

Tags: r, anova, experiment-design, goodness-of-fit, fractional-factorial

I have a half fraction factorial experiment for four factors, meaning I have eight experiments that I conduct. I expect that some of the responses are quadratic and not linear, thus I included centre points in my experiments, which introduces a ninth (zeroth) experiment. Indeed, quadratic responses seem possible from boxplots. Five repeats for all experiments were run, with the eight experiments in random order. The zeroth experiment, the centre points, have five repeats at the start of the runs, five repeats in the middle and five repeats at the end. This is to observe variation trends in operator skill or machine conditions during the whole experiment.

I am trying to run ANOVA in R to interpret the results. As far as I understand from a theoretical point of view, I should be able to run ANOVA on the eight experiments sorted by factor, but also on the lack of fit based on the centre points. A lack of fit would indicate that I have to do response surface modelling to find the optimum, and perhaps include a few more experiments in order to get the additional regression coefficients. I however have no idea how to implement this in R.

The textbook I use (Montgomery, Design and analysis of experiments) give a rudimentary test for lack of fit, where the average of the factorial point responses are compared with the average of the centre point responses. Mine is off by almost 10 %. They also give an explanation of how the lack of fit can be calculated by hand. This explanation is attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YeoKWfiwSCAksnAGIajAbqyQb_GSKtJN/view?usp=sharing) as a pdf.

I can run the ANOVA on the four factors with no problem.

```
summary(aov(t_σ[16:55] ~ A[16:55] + B[16:55] + C[16:55] + D[16:55], data))
```

which yields

```
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
A[16:55]     1   66.3    66.3   2.733   0.1072    
B[16:55]     1    1.5     1.5   0.062   0.8044    
C[16:55]     1  692.6   692.6  28.544 5.68e-06 ***
D[16:55]     1   89.1    89.1   3.674   0.0635 .  
Residuals   35  849.2    24.3                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

indicating that only Factor C has a significant effect. However, I have no idea how to add the lack of fit as an additional row in the ANOVA table based on the centre points. Is this possible, and can anyone advise on how I should do this? If not, is there another way to get the lack of fit in a separate operation?

Attached is my raw data. 'ekspnr' indicates the experiment number, where 0 indicates the centre point experiment. The data frame has been sorted according to experiment number, so that all the centre points are from 0 to 15, and the rest are from 16 to 55. 't_σ' is the response, and the A, B, C and D refers to the factors.

```
    ekspnr  t_σ A   B   C   D
0   0.0 27.951699   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
1   0.0 28.009995   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
2   0.0 27.939666   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
3   0.0 24.949808   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
4   0.0 25.536769   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
5   0.0 23.334088   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
6   0.0 24.637399   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
7   0.0 22.460906   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
8   0.0 20.429309   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
9   0.0 25.034200   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
10  0.0 21.047813   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
11  0.0 22.043904   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
12  0.0 22.177695   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
13  0.0 21.854369   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
14  0.0 19.923816   0.30    205.0   50.0    6.0
15  1.0 20.746215   0.18    190.0   10.0    2.0
16  1.0 18.999751   0.18    190.0   10.0    2.0
17  1.0 18.619490   0.18    190.0   10.0    2.0
18  1.0 18.820066   0.18    190.0   10.0    2.0
19  1.0 19.194736   0.18    190.0   10.0    2.0
20  2.0 19.088337   0.42    190.0   10.0    10.0
21  2.0 18.797644   0.42    190.0   10.0    10.0
22  2.0 18.377256   0.42    190.0   10.0    10.0
23  2.0 19.097554   0.42    190.0   10.0    10.0
24  2.0 17.815757   0.42    190.0   10.0    10.0
25  3.0 10.011159   0.18    220.0   10.0    10.0
26  3.0 13.538536   0.18    220.0   10.0    10.0
27  3.0 12.768532   0.18    220.0   10.0    10.0
28  3.0 13.711670   0.18    220.0   10.0    10.0
29  3.0 10.657853   0.18    220.0   10.0    10.0
30  4.0 22.674432   0.42    220.0   10.0    2.0
31  4.0 16.326696   0.42    220.0   10.0    2.0
32  4.0 21.479866   0.42    220.0   10.0    2.0
33  4.0 25.216749   0.42    220.0   10.0    2.0
34  4.0 21.089515   0.42    220.0   10.0    2.0
35  5.0 24.565803   0.18    190.0   90.0    10.0
36  5.0 29.021329   0.18    190.0   90.0    10.0
37  5.0 32.300469   0.18    190.0   90.0    10.0
38  5.0 32.673953   0.18    190.0   90.0    10.0
39  5.0 25.842299   0.18    190.0   90.0    10.0
40  6.0 20.402979   0.42    190.0   90.0    2.0
41  6.0 21.260363   0.42    190.0   90.0    2.0
42  6.0 21.916816   0.42    190.0   90.0    2.0
43  6.0 23.040326   0.42    190.0   90.0    2.0
44  6.0 15.786039   0.42    190.0   90.0    2.0
45  7.0 40.205180   0.18    220.0   90.0    2.0
46  7.0 31.956339   0.18    220.0   90.0    2.0
47  7.0 31.159483   0.18    220.0   90.0    2.0
48  7.0 32.386282   0.18    220.0   90.0    2.0
49  7.0 28.827811   0.18    220.0   90.0    2.0
50  8.0 23.726401   0.42    220.0   90.0    10.0
51  8.0 20.733421   0.42    220.0   90.0    10.0
52  8.0 28.205647   0.42    220.0   90.0    10.0
53  8.0 18.459101   0.42    220.0   90.0    10.0
54  8.0 21.004829   0.42    220.0   90.0    10.0
```

The only function I could find was pureErrorAnova() from the package alr3. However, when completing an example from my textbook (Montgomery, Design and analysis of experiments), this function does not yield the correct answers. The LoF and pure error has the wrong degrees of freedom, and their values are vastly different from the textbook. Moreover, the LoF is larger than the pure error in the table produced by the table, whereas it should be the other way around according to the textbook. The example refers to an earlier one. I attach them as pdfs [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kjuo7S0v9Ul8pL940PZYuY17jnSix-mV/view?usp=sharing) and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KfEcbYkvCvAUzaXQFABUQdzdcDQFch4u/view?usp=sharing). Note how the LoF is different than simply blocking the centre points as a separate block in a normal anova table.

Comment: I would suggest adding a 'centerpoint' variable that is 1 for the centerpoints and 0 for all other points, then add that to the model.  m1 <- lm(t~1+A+B+C+D + centerpoint, data=d)

Comment: In addition, a quick look at your centerpoints makes me think you had a drop in t over the course of the experiment, assuming the centerpoints are in the order actually conducted (5 then 5 then 5).

Comment: I have tried that, but that does not give me the lack of fit, it merely tells me whether the response average of the centre points differ significantly from the average of the responses per factor. The lack of fit tells me whether I can assume no second order effects from the factors. Comparing to JMP, the method of adding the centre points as a factor is very far off.

Comment: Yes, I have also noticed the drift in centre points. I am still considering whether that was due to experimental drift or some operator error.

Comment: "but that does not give me the lack of fit, it merely tells me whether the response average of the centre points differ significantly from the average of the responses per factor" --- would you explain to me how you think those two things differ?  Perhaps I'm not understanding part of your question.

Comment: (Arg, I must have missed the 5 minute limit to edit by seconds)

I think I'm confused due to this statement: "but also on the lack of fit based on the centre points"

Comment: @MichiganWater, I have updated the question statement to explain what I am looking for better, attaching three short pdf's from the textbook. I think that what you suggest is rather blocking the centre points than calculating the LoF. The one pdf explains the statistics used in calculating LoF, and the examples attached show what I am looking for. I might very well be wrong, I am fairly new to statistics, but that is how I understand it at the moment.

Comment: I think I understand a bit better.  For your specific question, I can't install alr3 because it is archived, and pureErrorAnova() isn't in alr4 for some reason, so I'm unable to try things with that function. Perhaps this? https://olsrr.rsquaredacademy.com/reference/ols_pure_error_anova.html
You might have to code it yourself.  A good starting point would be https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat501/lesson/2/2.11 and the pages leading up to that.
Finally, you might try contacting the author of the afex package for suggestions.

Comment: Feel free to post the output of pureErrorAnova, if that would help.
Also, before even looking at the centerpoints, see if you can get pureErrorAnova to give LOF and pure error for just the corner points data and have that match the book/JMP.